# Analysable documents format (extensions) in ElasticSearch

Tags: file, elasticsearch, format, documents

Do you please have any idea about the number of analysables formats in ElasticSearch?

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no limit - there are the following [default analysers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html):

- Standard Analyzer
- Simple Analyzer
- Whitespace Analyzer
- Stop Analyzer
- Keyword Analyzer
- Pattern Analyzer
- Language Analyzers
- Snowball Analyzer
- Custom Analyzer

But you can easily define your own analyser to meet your own specific needs.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Yes - as per my answer, you can create an analyser to support whatever format you are working with. Elasticsearch is designed to work with free text but I use it heavily with EDI formats such as EDIFACT, X12, XML, Fixed length, CSV, etc.

Comment: 300 is a meaningless, abitrary number - it can support any flavour of CSV or XML. But you could find it doesn't work well for some Fujitsu char encoded binary document containing packed decimals. It all depends on your requirement.